# Cassandra Sample Trigger how to get columnKey of of a delete operation

Tags: cassandra

I am experimenting with triggers,

my table is like,
CREATE TABLE df.test_company (
    pid uuid,
    id uuid,
    name text,
    PRIMARY KEY (pid, id)
);

when i invoke some thing like

DELETE from test_company WHERE pid = ccccdddd-d857-4e90-b1e5-df98a3d40cd6 AND id=aaaabbbb-d857-4e90-b1e5-df98a3d40cd6;

in my trigger code i can get the columnfamily and rowKey and also from metadata that it is a delete operation

but not able to get columnKey, for inserts i get cellName like aaaabbbb-d857-4e90-b1e5-df98a3d40cd6:name from which i can get the required id.

what should be done for delete ?

Comment: trying the trigger example at https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/examples/triggers/src/org/apache/cassandra/triggers/InvertedIndex.java   I found that the ByteBuffer key that comes in is the actual key and if you read it then it will not be saved, i had to do some thing like public Collection<Mutation> augment(ByteBuffer originalRowKey, ColumnFamily update) {
  ByteBuffer myRowKey = originalRowKey.duplicate();
  long firstLong = myRowKey.getLong(); 
  long secondLong = myRowKey.getLong(); ......}

Comment: in StorageProxy, i see that  
<code>
`// finish the paxos round w/ the desired updates`  
`// TODO turn null updates into delete?`  
`ColumnFamily updates = request.makeUpdates(current);`
</code>
is this the reason for not able to get the required data in case of deletes?

Comment: some how getting the required info from tombstone, RangeTombstone firstTombStone = deletionInfo.rangeIterator().next();.  in case of time series entity not able to get it :(

Comment: more specifically RangeTombstone firstTombStone = update.deletionInfo().rangeIterator().next();
    //here columnkey is of the form aaaabbbb-d857-4e90-b1e5-df98a3d40cda:_ we have to get rid of last two char
    String columnKeyString = metadata.comparator.getString(firstTombStone.min);
    mutationMap.put("rowKey",  columnKeyString.substring(0, (columnKeyString.length() - 2)) );